# C++ reference sub class in super class

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

I am little bit confused on referencing a sub class inside a super class in C++.
For example, given Java :

```
public class Entity {


  protected ComplexEntity _ce;

  public Entity() {

  }

  public ComplexEntity getCentity() {
    return _ce;
  }
}
```

Where ComplexEntity extends the entity.It works.In the sub class I call getCentity() no errors.

Now ,in C++ when I write something like that:

```
 #pragma once

 #include "maininclude.h"
 #include "ExtendedEntity.h"
 using namespace std;

 class EntityBase
 {
 public:
    EntityBase(void);
    EntityBase(const string &name);

    ~EntityBase(void);

 protected:

    ExtendedEntity* _extc;
    string   _name;
 };
```

I am getting compiler error:

```
  error C2504: 'Entity' : base class undefined
```

In the classes which inherit from this Entity.Why does that happen?

Is it completely unacceptable in C++?

May be Entity must be abstract ?
I would like to get suggestions on possible workarounds.

Comment: Do you have any C++ code to show?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may consider using [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern), cut/paste from Wikipedia:

```
// The Curiously Recurring Template Pattern (CRTP)
template<class Derived>
class Base
{
    Derived* getDerived() { return static_cast<Derived*>(this); }
};

class Derived : public Base<Derived>
{
    // ...
};
```

Comment: This pattern can be problematic if the derived is of different type than the reference to it in the base class. I think it is good where there's only one derived to one base.No, sorry, I am wrong. Discard this comment

Answer (score 1):

A class in C++ needs to know the size of all its members and of all its superclasses. Class `Entity` does not know the size of it's subclass `ComplexEntity`, unless class `ComplexEntity` is defined before class `Entity`. But then, class `ComplexEntity` does not know the size of its superclass `Entity`.

This problem exists in C++, because class members are accessed using simple offset calculation. You can work around this, by forward declaring the derived class and using pointers as members:

```
class Extended; // declare the derived class

class Base {  // define the base class
  Extended* e; // you cannot use Extended e here,
               // because the class is not defined yet.
};

class Extended : public Base {}; // define the derived class
```

Comment: Entity does not need to know anything about ExtendedEntity because Entity holds an ExtendedEntity by pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is like the following:

```
struct D : B {}; // error: B doesn't mean anything at this point

struct B {
    D *d;
};
```

Your header ExtendedEntity.h is trying to use the definition of Entity before Entity is defined.

You need to change your code to this:

```
struct D;

struct B {
    D *d;
};

struct D : B {};
```

Comment: Do you mean I have to put a variable of the ExtendedEntity before the Entity header ?Don't get it with structs example...

Comment: OK , now I see what you mean. @Oswald put it in a quite descriptive way.Thanks.